# Почему обработчик события не работает через include?

Tags: java, android, ооп, android-on-click

Нужна in-app клавиатура,чтобы спокойно мог из разных активити подключать. Код следующий:

Клавиатура, задаем кнопки и т.д.:

```html
public class MyKeyboard extends ConstraintLayout implements View.OnClickListener {


    private Button button_q,
            button_w,
            button_e,
            button_r,
            button_t,
            button_y,
            button_u,
            button_i,
            button_o,
            button_p,
            button_a,
            button_s,
            button_d,
            button_f,
            button_g,
            button_h,
            button_j,
            button_k,
            button_l,
            button_z,
            button_x,
            button_c,
            button_v,
            button_b,
            button_n,
            button_m,
            buttonDelete, buttonEnter;

   
    private SparseArray<String> keyValues = new SparseArray<>();
    private InputConnection inputConnection;

    public MyKeyboard(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }


    private void init() {

        button_q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_q);
        button_q.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_w = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_w);
        button_w.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_e = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_e);
        button_e.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_r = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_r);
        button_r.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_t = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_t);
        button_t.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_y = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_y);
        button_y.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_u = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_u);
        button_u.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_i = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_i);
        button_i.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_o = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_o);
        button_o.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_p = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_p);
        button_p.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_a);
        button_a.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_s = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_s);
        button_s.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_d = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_d);
        button_d.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_f = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_f);
        button_f.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_g = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_g);
        button_g.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_h = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_h);
        button_h.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_h = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_h);
        button_h.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_j = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_j);
        button_j.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_k = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_k);
        button_k.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_l = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_l);
        button_l.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_z = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_z);
        button_z.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_x);
        button_x.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_c);
        button_c.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_v = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_v);
        button_v.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_b);
        button_b.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_n = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_n);
        button_n.setOnClickListener(this);

        button_m = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_m);
        button_m.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(this);


        buttonEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_space);
        buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);

        keyValues.put(R.id.button_q, "q");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_w, "w");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_e, "e");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_r, "r");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_t, "t");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_y, "y");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_u, "u");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_i, "i");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_o, "o");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_p, "p");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_a, "a");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_s, "s");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_d, "d");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_f, "f");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_g, "g");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_h, "h");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_j, "j");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_k, "k");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_l, "l");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_z, "z");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_x, "x");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_c, "c");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_v, "v");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_b, "b");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_n, "n");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_m, "m");
        keyValues.put(R.id.button_space, " ");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (inputConnection == null)
            return;

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button_delete) {
            CharSequence selectedText = inputConnection.getSelectedText(0);

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selectedText)) {
                inputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            } else {
                inputConnection.commitText("", 1);
            }
        } else {

            String value = keyValues.get(view.getId());
            inputConnection.commitText(value, 1);
        }
    }

    public void setInputConnection(InputConnection ic) {
        inputConnection = ic;
    }
}
```

Активити, где требуется клавиатура:

```html
package com.tsvetkovopozdal.lalaeng;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.speech.tts.Voice;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;

import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;

public class WordConstructor extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_constructor);

        Bundle argumets = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String name = argumets.get("text").toString();
        TextView a = findViewById(R.id.word_constructor_hello);
        a.setText(name);

        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(name.length())});       this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        
        MyKeyboard keyboard = new MyKeyboard(getApplicationContext());
        
        InputConnection ic = editText.onCreateInputConnection(new EditorInfo());
        keyboard.setInputConnection(ic);
  
    }


}
```

Подключается через include

```html
<include
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    layout="@layout/keyboard"/>
```

Суть проблемы: при вызове init() из конструктора класса MyKeyboard студия выдает следующую ошибку

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Порывшись в сети, нашел посты, где у людей данная ошибка возникала при использовании findViewById до вызова методов onCreate() и setContentView(), это вроде бы не мой случай, так как создаю экземпляр класса после отрисовки view и в самом методе onCreate. Спустя половину дня поисков, зачем-то все таки заменил конструктор класса MyKeyboard на метод onCreate и вызвал init() из него, в итоге ошибка пропала, все запускается, но теперь в метод init() не заходит(дебажил toast'ом).

**Вопрос:** как в данном случае повесить слушаетели на кнопки клавиатуры, чтобы все работало через include? То есть чтобы не переносить логику клавиатуры, слушателей и т.д. в код активити.

Upd:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Keyboard.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/qwer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/asd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.95" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_q"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="q"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_w"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_w"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="w"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_q"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_e"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_e"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="e"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_w"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_r"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_r"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="r"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_e"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_t"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_t"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="t"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_r"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_y"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_y"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="y"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_t"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_u"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_u"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="u"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_y"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_i"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_i"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="i"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_u"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_o"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_o"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="o"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_i"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_p"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_p"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="p"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_o"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="a"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_s"

        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_s"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="s"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_a"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_d"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_d"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="d"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_f"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_s"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_f"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="f"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_d"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/button_g"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_g"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="g"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_f"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_h"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_h"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="h"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_g"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_j"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_j"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="i"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_h"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_k"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_k"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="k"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_j"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_l"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_l"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="l"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_k"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_delete"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="m"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/qwer"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_l"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_z"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="z"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_x"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_x"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="x"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_z"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_c"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_c"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="c"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_x"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_v"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_v"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="v"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_c"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_b"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="b"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_v"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_n"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_n"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="n"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_b"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_m"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_m"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="m"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_n"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/button_space"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_space"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        android:text="space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/asd"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/button_m"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</merge>
```

WordConstructor.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/wordcons"

    tools:context="com.tsvetkovopozdal.lalaeng.WordConstructor">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word_constructor_hello"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="gravity"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/transcript"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_volume_up_black_24dp"
        android:text=" [idfjdosfom]"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/word_constructor_hello"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4" />
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7" />

<include
    layout="@layout/keyboard"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

После добавления инфлейтера вьюшки находятся, но onClick не срабатывает, будто слушаетель вешается на другие экземпляры кнопок.

Comment: Вы не тот контекст передаёте. Передавайте this в конструктор клавиатуры

Comment: Попробовал, findViewbyId теперь отрабатывает, но приложение теперь крашится на попытке повесить слушатель на кнопку. Приложил ошибку к вопросу

Comment: Может дело в том, что вы вашу разметку в классе клавиатуры не используете? Попробуйте её заинфлейтить туда. Ну и саму разметку покажите

Comment: Разметку прикрепил, заинфлетил, как написали ниже, но onClick не работает все равно

Comment: Должно работать. Попробуйте добавить вывод в логи в онКлик метод. И попробуйте полностью переустановить приложение - может обновление кода глючит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты пытаешься обратиться к вьюшкам, которые лежат в `.xml`, но твоя вьюшка с клавиатурой не знает ничего о том самом `.xml`, поэтому тебе нужно ее заинфлейтить.

Для этого в начало `init()` добавь следующее:

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.твой_айди_разметки, this, true)
```

Кроме того, лейаут разметки желательно обернуть не в ConstraintLayout, а в merge, это избавит тебя от лишней прослойки из вьюх на этапе инфлейтинга.

И ещё -- использовать Constraint на вьюшке с клавиатурой, наверное, не лучшая идея, ибо получается слишком много связей, и measure/layout pass может занять довольно много времени.

Comment: Добавил, с вьюшками решилась проблема, при сборке ошибок нет, но onClick все равно не срабатывает. Вопрос xml'ками дополнил.

Comment: Смотрите, в onCreate MainActivity вы создали экземпляр класса Keyboard вместо того, чтобы обратиться к ней напрямую из .xml. В итоге вы связали клавиатуру с совсем другим обработчиком. Решение следующее -- в WordConstructor.xml присвоить id элементу с клавиатурой, который вы добавили через include. Затем обратиться к этому элементу через findViewById внутри onCreate активити, это и будет нужная вам клавиатура. И еще -- вы использовали merge, это классно, но чтобы не страдать в editor'e, добавьте tools:parentTag=ConstraintLayout, и тогда эдитор будет правильно рисовать вьюшки

Comment: В общем, как сделать это грамотно через include, так и не понял, буду копать дальше. Но сейчас сам include в word_constructor.xml  заменил на <com.tsvetkovopozdal.lalaeng.MyKeyboard android:id="@+id/keyboard"> и все окей. Спасибо.